# How to Totally Erase PyCharm on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: dpkg, snap, pycharm, snap-store

I made a mistake by installing pycharm-community from jetbrains on my Ubuntu 20.04 from a tar file available [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/download-thanks.html?platform=linux&code=PCC&_ga=2.183040486.1573168195.1655867850-550764702.1653559203&_gl=1*1j54bfx*_ga*NTUwNzY0NzAyLjE2NTM1NTkyMDM.*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY1NTg2Nzg1MC45LjEuMTY1NTg2Nzg5NS4xNQ..). Now, seems it is working, but each time I have to start pycharm as a script from

```
/opt/pycharm-community-2022.1.2/bin/
```

There is no executable, or command line binary to start it.

So I want to completely uninstall this instance of Pycharm, along with every possible configuration or memory from my system, and reinstall it by snap. But I cannot find a way to remove pycharm installation. Even when I try dpkg, I get this

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge pycharm         
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove pycharm which isn't installed
```

So how do I remove it to be able to reinstall from snap?

Comment: A tarball is just a group of random files. It's not a *package*, and cannot be affected by a package manager. There is no standard way to install or uninstall a tarball (which is, again, just a group of random files). Some file within that group must include the custom instructions for installing and uninstalling that group of random files. You must find those instructions, or ask the tarball's maker for those instructions. Yes, that's an awful way to install software -- that's why installing from tarballs was superseded a generation ago by software packages and package managers.

Comment: @user535733 so if I install parallely from snap store, will it conflict with my tarball installation? Or is it hard to say?

Comment: Best practice is to remove the tarball-provided files before installing the snap. We don't know if A will conflict with B, since we have not tested that. YOU are testing that.